# Scikit-image: cannot import name 'label'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, scikit-image

I have some scripts that use `skimage.measure.label`. On my old laptop (Debian 7, Python 2) these scripts worked perfectly. Recently, when I got a new laptop, I moved to Debian 8 and Python 3. Now these scripts cannot import `skimage.measure.label`:

```
File "image_converter.py", line 8, in <module>
    from skimage.measure import label
ImportError: cannot import name 'label'
```

All of the other imports are working fine:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.filter import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.measure import regionprops
from skimage.color import label2rgb
import skimage.io as ski_io
```

`pip3 list` says:

```
(...)
scikit-image (0.9.3)
(...)
```

Python version is 3.4.3.

What has happened there? Has scikit-image (re-)moved `measure.label`?

In the **official documentation** it is still listed: [skimage.measure.label](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no function `label` in module `measure` for release 0.9 (see http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/api/skimage.measure.html).

Basically, you should update your version of `skimage`. The most recent version is 0.12.3. Python 3.4 is officially tested against, so you shouldn't expect any troubles with compatibility.